# Starting a new Activity Crash

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm following the Starting Another Activity tutorial for android developers and followed all the steps however my app keeps crashing when I try press the button to start the new activity. Here is the code I'm using and my logcat.

```
package com.example.mysecondapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Build;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.mysecondapp.MESSAGE";

    public void sendMessage(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        Log.d("intent", "intentstarted");
        startActivity(intent);
        Log.d("activity", "activitty");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}






package com.example.mysecondapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

log cat:

```
06-28 20:11:47.013: I/Process(308): Sending signal. PID: 308 SIG: 9
06-28 20:25:17.352: I/dalvikvm(336): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getActivityLogo, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>
06-28 20:25:17.352: W/dalvikvm(336): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 319: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getActivityLogo (Landroid/content/ComponentName;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
06-28 20:25:17.352: D/dalvikvm(336): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x008b
06-28 20:25:17.352: I/dalvikvm(336): Could not find method android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.loadLogo, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>
06-28 20:25:17.352: W/dalvikvm(336): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 315: Landroid/content/pm/ApplicationInfo;.loadLogo (Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
06-28 20:25:17.352: D/dalvikvm(336): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0099
06-28 20:25:17.372: D/dalvikvm(336): VFY: dead code 0x008e-0092 in Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
06-28 20:25:17.372: D/dalvikvm(336): VFY: dead code 0x009c-00a0 in Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
06-28 20:25:20.082: W/KeyCharacterMap(336): No keyboard for id 0
06-28 20:25:20.082: W/KeyCharacterMap(336): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-28 20:25:37.843: D/dalvikvm(336): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3702 objects / 228664 bytes in 201ms
06-28 20:25:37.863: D/intent(336): intentstarted
06-28 20:25:37.903: D/activity(336): activitty
06-28 20:25:38.393: E/FragmentManager(336): No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.mysecondapp:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{45fa00f0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
06-28 20:25:38.393: E/FragmentManager(336): Activity state:
06-28 20:25:38.404: D/FragmentManager(336):   Local FragmentActivity 45f8a0b0 State:
06-28 20:25:38.413: D/FragmentManager(336):     mCreated=truemResumed=false mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
06-28 20:25:38.423: D/FragmentManager(336):     mLoadersStarted=false
06-28 20:25:38.423: D/FragmentManager(336):   Active Fragments in 45f776c8:
06-28 20:25:38.443: D/FragmentManager(336):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{45fa00f0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
06-28 20:25:38.443: D/FragmentManager(336):       mFragmentId=#7f05003c mContainerId=#7f05003c mTag=null
06-28 20:25:38.453: D/FragmentManager(336):       mState=0 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0
06-28 20:25:38.463: D/FragmentManager(336):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
06-28 20:25:38.463: D/FragmentManager(336):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
06-28 20:25:38.483: D/FragmentManager(336):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
06-28 20:25:38.483: D/FragmentManager(336):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{45f776c8 in DisplayMessageActivity{45f8a0b0}}
06-28 20:25:38.483: D/FragmentManager(336):       mActivity=com.example.mysecondapp.DisplayMessageActivity@45f8a0b0
06-28 20:25:38.503: D/FragmentManager(336):   Added Fragments:
06-28 20:25:38.503: D/FragmentManager(336):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{45fa00f0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
06-28 20:25:38.513: D/FragmentManager(336):   FragmentManager misc state:
06-28 20:25:38.523: D/FragmentManager(336):     mActivity=com.example.mysecondapp.DisplayMessageActivity@45f8a0b0
06-28 20:25:38.523: D/FragmentManager(336):     mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$2@45f550d0
06-28 20:25:38.542: D/FragmentManager(336):     mCurState=2 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
06-28 20:25:38.542: D/FragmentManager(336):   View Hierarchy:
06-28 20:25:38.563: D/FragmentManager(336):     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{45f87538 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
06-28 20:25:38.563: D/FragmentManager(336):       android.widget.FrameLayout{45f81e98 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0}
06-28 20:25:38.573: D/FragmentManager(336):         android.widget.LinearLayout{45fa71b0 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
06-28 20:25:38.583: D/FragmentManager(336):           android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{45f9d1e0 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f05001b app:id/action_bar_container}
06-28 20:25:38.583: D/FragmentManager(336):             android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView{45f67418 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f05001c app:id/action_bar}
06-28 20:25:38.603: D/FragmentManager(336):               android.widget.LinearLayout{45fa99d0 G.....C. ... 0,0-0,0}
06-28 20:25:38.603: D/FragmentManager(336):                 android.widget.ImageView{45f7d428 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f050021 app:id/up}
06-28 20:25:38.603: D/FragmentManager(336):                 android.widget.LinearLayout{45f7c720 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
06-28 20:25:38.623: D/FragmentManager(336):                   android.widget.TextView{45f5fa98 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f050022 app:id/action_bar_title}
06-28 20:25:38.623: D/FragmentManager(336):                   android.widget.TextView{45f622b8 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f050023 app:id/action_bar_subtitle}
06-28 20:25:38.633: D/FragmentManager(336):               android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{45f700c8 VFE...C. ... 0,0-0,0}
06-28 20:25:38.633: D/FragmentManager(336):                 android.widget.ImageView{45f3ebf0 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f050021 app:id/up}
06-28 20:25:38.652: D/FragmentManager(336):                 android.widget.ImageView{45f769d0 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f050014 app:id/home}
06-28 20:25:38.652: D/FragmentManager(336):             android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{45fa1430 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f05001d app:id/action_context_bar}
06-28 20:25:38.673: D/FragmentManager(336):           android.widget.FrameLayout{45f92928 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020002 android:id/content}
06-28 20:25:38.673: D/FragmentManager(336):             android.widget.TextView{45f64db0 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0}
06-28 20:25:38.683: D/FragmentManager(336):           android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{45f99900 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f05001e app:id/split_action_bar}
06-28 20:25:38.693: D/AndroidRuntime(336): Shutting down VM
06-28 20:25:38.693: W/dalvikvm(336): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mysecondapp/com.example.mysecondapp.DisplayMessageActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.mysecondapp:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{45fa00f0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.mysecondapp:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{45fa00f0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:930)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3781)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2636)
06-28 20:25:38.733: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  ... 11 more
06-28 20:25:41.702: I/Process(336): Sending signal. PID: 336 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making an error in your second activity remove this line of code in the second activity and it should work

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();         
}
```

You are trying to add the PlaceholderFragment to the R.id.container, when the content view of the second activity is the TextView which does not have that container.hope this helps